# Angular $resource adding quotes

Tags: angularjs, mongodb

I am facing an encoding issue with $resource.

I have the following in my controller where `Service` is a plain $resource service:

```
get(val) {
  return this.Service.query(
    {
      $text: {$search: val}
    }
  ).$promise;
}
```

This is what my server is receiving: `{ '$text': '{"$search":"Test"}' }`.

The set of quotes around `{"$search":"Test"}` is causing mongo to say:

> $text expects an object

Is there an easy way to remove those quotes?

**Edit** I am using yo's angular-fullstack

```
router.get('/', auth.isAuthenticated() , controller.index);
export function index(req, res) {
  console.log(req.query); //This is the above log output
return Patient.find(req.query).exec()
   .then(respondWithResult(res))
   .catch(handleError(res));
}
```

Comment: inspect actual request in dev tools network to see how it is actually sent. Need to narrow down which end is causing problem

Comment: The Url Request does not include the quotes. `$text=%7B%22$search%22:%22Test%22%7D` Is that what you are asking?

Comment: so problem is at server but no code shown for there

Comment: you need to parse `req.query.$test` probably. Try `console.log(JSON.parse(req.query.$test));`

Comment: I think you mean $text. I get `{ '$search': 'Test' }` no quotes.

Comment: oops..that was a typo.. so it works now?

Comment: No it still does not work. I added my query to the edit as that might be where the issue lies.

Comment: if `$text` needs to be part of `find` you need to create an object from the parsed data

Comment: I was scared you would say that. The $text is the query but it's not in every request and I was trying to keep the server code as generic as possible.

Comment: post it instead of get, or change the params in `$resource` like .....`{find:{ $text: {$search: val}}`...then parse `req.query.find`